# Rails4 API @current_user getting assigned 1 if not given any value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am Rails 4 with devise. I have a base controller

```
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  before_action :current_user

 def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find_by(authentication_token: request.headers['Authorization'])
 end

end
```

`Whenever I send A request with authorization header, @current_user gets the correct user id, but when I don't send Authorization token, @current_user is taking up 1. Why it's getting assigned 1? Please help.

Comment: Do you have users in your database with no authorization token?

Comment: Yes, I have one without token, so thats why its taking up one, Thank you very much, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no token passed in the request headers you'll end up doing

```
User.find_by(authorization_token: nil)
```

Which will return a user whose authorization_token column is null (if there is one), so you need to check that the header is present.

You may be interested in the `devise-token_authenticatable` gem which implements a token based authentication strategy for devise (extracted from earlier versions of devise)

Comment: Thanks for the explananation :) I thought devise-token_authenticable is depricated.

Comment: Well it was deprecated and then removed from devise but then resurected as a gem.